# Increase 10% additional rows in each row group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp #Appointments table, I need to increase 10% row in each week group,

```
Row CustomerNo  AppointmentDate AppointmentStatus   WeekGroup
1   963583273   01/11/2021  Vacant  1
2   964584274   01/11/2021  Vacant  1
3   965585275   02/11/2021  Vacant  1
4   966586276   02/11/2021  Vacant  1
5   967587277   03/11/2021  Vacant  1
6   968588278   03/11/2021  Vacant  1
7   969589279   04/11/2021  Vacant  1
8   970590280   04/11/2021  Vacant  1
9   971591281   05/11/2021  Vacant  1
10  972592282   05/11/2021  Vacant  1
11  973593283   08/11/2021  Vacant  2
12  974594284   08/11/2021  Vacant  2
13  975595285   08/11/2021  Vacant  2
14  976596286   08/11/2021  Vacant  2
15  977597287   09/11/2021  Vacant  2
16  978598288   09/11/2021  Vacant  2
17  979599289   09/11/2021  Vacant  2
18  980600290   09/11/2021  Vacant  2
19  981601291   10/11/2021  Vacant  2
20  982602292   10/11/2021  Vacant  2
21  983603293   10/11/2021  Vacant  2
22  984604294   10/11/2021  Vacant  2
23  985605295   11/11/2021  Vacant  2
24  986606296   11/11/2021  Vacant  2
25  987607297   11/11/2021  Vacant  2
26  988608298   11/11/2021  Vacant  2
27  989609299   12/11/2021  Vacant  2
28  990610300   12/11/2021  Vacant  2
29  991611301   12/11/2021  Vacant  2
30  998618308   15/11/2021  Vacant  3
31  984604294   15/11/2021  Vacant  3
32  985605295   16/11/2021  Vacant  3
33  986606296   16/11/2021  Vacant  3
34  987607297   17/11/2021  Vacant  3
35  988608298   17/11/2021  Vacant  3
36  989609299   18/11/2021  Vacant  3
37  990610300   18/11/2021  Vacant  3
38  991611301   19/11/2021  Vacant  3
39  992612302   19/11/2021  Vacant  3
```

But I can inflate only for the first week group, but I am unable to dynamically apply the 10% (or inflate) to the following weeks,
can someone please help to loop or dynamically increase 10% extra rows in each WeekGroup? I need the result table to look like the below.

```
Row CustomerNo  AppointmentDate AppointmentStatus   WeekGroup   
1   963583273   01/11/2021  Vacant  1   
2   964584274   01/11/2021  Vacant  1   
3   965585275   02/11/2021  Vacant  1   
4   966586276   02/11/2021  Vacant  1   
5   967587277   03/11/2021  Vacant  1   
6   968588278   03/11/2021  Vacant  1   
7   969589279   04/11/2021  Vacant  1   
8   970590280   04/11/2021  Vacant  1   
9   971591281   05/11/2021  Vacant  1   
10  972592282   05/11/2021  Vacant  1   
11                  10% extra row
12  973593283   08/11/2021  Vacant  2   
13  974594284   08/11/2021  Vacant  2   
14  975595285   08/11/2021  Vacant  2   
15  976596286   08/11/2021  Vacant  2   
16  977597287   09/11/2021  Vacant  2   
17  978598288   09/11/2021  Vacant  2   
18  979599289   09/11/2021  Vacant  2   
19  980600290   09/11/2021  Vacant  2   
20  981601291   10/11/2021  Vacant  2   
21  982602292   10/11/2021  Vacant  2   
22  983603293   10/11/2021  Vacant  2   
23  984604294   10/11/2021  Vacant  2   
24  985605295   11/11/2021  Vacant  2   
25  986606296   11/11/2021  Vacant  2   
26  987607297   11/11/2021  Vacant  2   
27  988608298   11/11/2021  Vacant  2   
28  989609299   12/11/2021  Vacant  2   
29  990610300   12/11/2021  Vacant  2   
30  991611301   12/11/2021  Vacant  2   
31                  10% extra row
32                  10% extra row
33  998618308   15/11/2021  Vacant  3   
34  984604294   15/11/2021  Vacant  3   
35  985605295   16/11/2021  Vacant  3   
36  986606296   16/11/2021  Vacant  3   
37  987607297   17/11/2021  Vacant  3   
38  988608298   17/11/2021  Vacant  3   
39  989609299   18/11/2021  Vacant  3   
40  990610300   18/11/2021  Vacant  3   
41  991611301   19/11/2021  Vacant  3   
42  992612302   19/11/2021  Vacant  3   
43                  10% extra row
```

This is what I have so far:

```
--INFLATE 10% appointment rows
DECLARE @AddRows AS INT
SELECT 
@AddRows=ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(CASE WHEN AppointmentStatus='Vacant' THEN 1 END))/100*10,0)+CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(CASE WHEN AppointmentStatus='Vacant' THEN 1 END))
FROM #Appointments;


CREATE TABLE #ResultsTable
(
 CustomerNo NVARCHAR(20), 
 AppointmentDate DATE,
 AppointmentStatus NVARCHAR(100),
 WeekGroup INT
)
INSERT INTO #ResultsTable(CustomerNo, AppointmentDate,AppointmentStatus,WeekGroup)
SELECT CustomerNo, AppointmentDate,AppointmentStatus, WeekGroup  FROM #Appointments WHERE AppointmentStatus='Vacant' and WeekGroup=1

WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM #ResultsTable) <@AddRows)
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #ResultsTable VALUES ('', '', '','')
 END

SELECT * FROM #ResultsTable
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: `VALUES ('', '', '','')` - your added row has no any connection with any week. You can just add 10% of all rows of the table.

Comment: I am using MS SSMS

Comment: Serg, I need 10% for each week group in the row order, not 10% for all rows of the table. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of row-numbering and a window function to get which rows to duplicate. Then use an apply to conditionally add extra rows

```sql
SELECT
  v.CustomerNo,
  v.AppointmentDate,
  v.AppointmentStatus,
  v.WeekGroup
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Total =  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY WeekGroup),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WeekGroup ORDER BY NEWID())  -- newid is random
    FROM #Appointments a
    WHERE AppointmentStatus = 'Vacant'
) a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      a.CustomerNo,
      a.AppointmentDate,
      a.AppointmentStatus,
      a.WeekGroup
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      a.CustomerNo,
      a.AppointmentDate,
      a.AppointmentStatus,
      a.WeekGroup
    WHERE rn <= (Total + 9) / 10  -- alternatively CEILING(Total / 10.0, 0)
) v
```